# Generic interfaces which type implements another interface

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

Could somebody explain why it doesn't work.

I have two db context. And one common method with different return types and different queries.

```
public interface IDataFetcher<T> where T : IMarker
{
    public List<T> GetData();
}
public interface IFetchServiceOne<T> : IDataFetcher<T> where T : IMarker
{
//maybe some methods here
}
public interface IFetchServiceTwo<T> : IDataFetcher<T> where T : IMarker
{
//maybe some different methods here
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class FetchServiceOne<T> : IFetchServiceOne<T> where T : IMarker
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public FetchServiceOne(DBContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public List<CrucialData> GetData()
    {
        var example = _dbContext.Test.ToList();
        return example;
    }
}
public class FetchServiceTwo<T> : IFetchServiceOne<T> where T : IMarker
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public FetchServiceTwo(DBContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public List<CrucialDataTwo> GetData()
    {
        var example = _dbContext.Test2.ToList();
        return example;
    }
}
public class CrucialData: IMarker
{
//some properries
}
public class CrucialDataTwo: IMarker
{
//another properries
}
```

In the output I'm getting compile error:

> Error (active) CS0738  'FetchService' does not implement interface member 'IDataFetcher.GetData()'. 'FetchService.GetData()' cannot implement 'IDataFetcher.GetData()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'List'.

Comment: Your method is `public List<T> GetData();`. You're defining the generic class `class FetchServiceOne<T> : IFetchServiceOne<T>`, which means you need to implement that method as `public List<T> GetData()`. However you're trying to use `public List<CrucialData> GetData()`.

Comment: What if someone did `new FetchServiceOne<CrucialDataTwo>().GetData()`? The method you're trying to write would return a `List<CrucialData>`, but the caller is expecting a `List<CrucialDataTwo>`

Comment: oh I see... could you give a pice of advice how save flexibility for both realisation but return for FetchServiceTwo or FetchServiceOne specific List. Now there are only two db fetch, but it could be more. Common is GetData method in 100% cases.

Comment: Look at @GuruStron's answer. If you want to return `_dbContext.Test.ToList()`, and that's a `List<CrucialData>`, then your method needs to return a `List<CrucialData>`, which means that it needs to implement `IDataFetcher<CrucialData>`, not `IDataFetcher<T>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `IFetchServiceOne` and `IFetchServiceTwo` (and their implementations) should be "concrete" interfaces which implement closed versione of `IDataFetcher`. I.e.:

```cs
public interface IFetchServiceOne : IDataFetcher<CrucialData>
{
    //maybe some methods here
}

public class FetchServiceOne : IFetchServiceOne
{
    // ...

    public List<CrucialData> GetData()
    {
        // implementation ...
        return default;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can't guarantee that `T` requested by user will be `CrucialData` for `FetchServiceOne` (i.e. `FetchServiceOne<CrucialDataTwo>.GetData()` ...)

Or just:

```cs
public class FetchServiceOne : IDataFetcher<CrucialData>
{
   // ...
}
```

Without need for introduction of the intermediate interface.

Note that for EF you can create a generic implementation via [`Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-6.0) method if needed:

```cs
public class FetchServiceOne<T> : IDataFetcher<T> where T : IMarker
{
    private readonly DBContext _dbContext;

    public FetchServiceOne(DBContext dbContext) => _dbContext = dbContext;

    public List<T> GetData()
    {
        var example = _dbContext.Set<T>.ToList();
        return example;
    }
}
```

But this will fail at runtime if there is no matching `DbSet` property setup for provided `T` type.